# Pressing enter key on chrome using pyautogui

Tags: python, pyautogui

Rookie here, I've been trying to find a solution to this for 3 straight hours. I want to share my private videos with 12 people on YouTube and I don't want to write 12 e-mail addresses one by one each time I upload a video. So I tried to write a simple code for this using pyautogui.I made a delay because I need time to click on the e-mail box on chrome after I launch my program. The issue here is, I need to press enter after each time I write an e-mail address but It fails to do this. I need some help about this.

Here is my code:

```
import pyautogui as df
import time
time.sleep(3)
df.typewrite("my friend's email") 
df.press("enter")
```

Note: Also tried using this but I couldn't manage to run pynput properly on vcs or pycharm(despite I installed pynput package on pycharm)

```
import time

import pynput

from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller
time.sleep(3)

keyboard = Controller()
df.typewrite("my friend's email") 
keyboard.press(Key.enter)
keyboard.release(Key.enter)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As shown [here](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html#keyboard-functions), perhaps you can do `df.typewrite("my friend's email\n")`. Note the trailing `'\n'`.

Answer (score 0):

For `pyautogui`

Change `df.press("enter")` to `df.hotkey('enter')`